# Django 1.7 does not find apps anymore, why?

Tags: python, django

Since trying Django 1.7 and Python 3 I am having real difficulties with it finding my apps and even installed packages for example:

```
> virtualenv -p python3 env
> source env/bin/activate
> pip3 install oauth2_provider
```

Then I setup  oauth2_provider as I have done many times with Django 1.6 and Python 2.7, but in Django 1.7 and Python 3 I get this error...

```
 File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/test/env/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/test/test/core/urls.py", line 9, in <module>
    url(r'^api/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider')),
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/test/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 28, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/test/env/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'oauth2_provider.urls'
```

URLs:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',


    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^api/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider')),

)
```

I have checked `/env/libs/python3.4/site-packages/oauth2_provider` and all there is a `__init__.py`  is that right? I have tried reinstalling, even starting again, but no joy! Any ideas what is happening here?

I also have another question open which is the same app and maybe related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998841/lookuperror-app-profiles-doesnt-have-a-model

Is this Django 1.7, Python 3? All of which is the first time I have used these versions.

Comment: Have you tried Python 2 and Django 1.7 or Python 3 and Django 1.6 to try to track down exactly what the problem is? My guess would be that oauth2_provider (is is [this package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oauth2_provider/) package, you haven't linked to it?) doesn't support Python 3.

Comment: Ok @Alasdair yep it appears that Python 3 is not supported foroauth2_provider installs correctly under python 2.7. is there a fork?

Comment: I haven't used the oauth2_provider before, and I don't know whether there's a Python 3 fork.

Comment: switch to https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit seems to work with 3. Thank you I am happy to accept your answer if posted i.e. its not Python 3 compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [oauth2_provider](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oauth2_provider/) package does not appear to be Python 3 compatible.